# Reduce number of datapoints using crossfilter

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Let's say I have a 100 years worth of monthly data, total of 1200 data points, see bottom.

To plot a tiny overview line chart (e.g. just 100 data points) I have to do it manually by grouping. For instance, group the data by year, then get the average of 12 months value, iterate through every group, then finally reduced the data points to 100.

Instead of this approach, is there a convenient way using crossfilter or any other library?

```
[
    { date: 1900-01, value: 72000000000},
    { date: 1900-02, value: 58000000000},
    { date: 1900-03, value:  2900000000},
    { date: 1900-04, value: 31000000000},
    { date: 1900-05, value: 33000000000},
    ...
    { date: 1999-11, value: 30000000000},
    { date: 1999-12, value: 10000000000},
]
```

Comment: This question is specific enough. Close vote is inappropriate (and rude to a new user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be the same algorithm no matter which library you use, just different ways of specifying it. In this case d3.nest is probably the easiest way to do this, but if you want quick filtering, the crossfilter way isn't too bad.

The difference between using d3.nest and crossfilter is that we're not constructing an array of values, just a single value. So we'll maintain both sum and count.

We'll also need to specify what happens when a row is removed from a bin.

```
var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  // it's best to convert fields before passing to crossfilter
  // because crossfilter will look at them many times
  d.date = parse(d.key);
});
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var yearDim = cf.dimension(d => d3.timeYear(d.date));
var yearAvgGroup = yearDim.group().reduce(
  function(p, v) { // add
    p.sum += v.value;
    ++p.count;
    p.avg = p.sum/p.count;
    return p;
  },
  function(p, v) { // remove
    p.sum -= v.value;
    --p.count;
    p.avg = p.count ? p.sum/p.count : 0;
    return p;
  },
  function() { // init
    return {sum: 0, count: 0, avg: 0};
  }
);
```

Now `yearAvgGroup.all()` will return an array of key/value pairs, where the key is the year, and the value contains `sum`, `count`, and `avg`.

Crossfilter doesn't make this problem particularly convenient to solve, but [reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio) has a helper function for this:

```
var yearAvgGroup = yearDim.group();
reductio().avg(d => d.value);
```

Note: it doesn't matter unless you have ton of data, but it's more efficient to only compute sum and count in the group, and compute the average when it's needed.

If you're using dc.js, you can use `valueAccessor` for this:

```
// remove avg lines from the above, and
chart.dimension(yearDim)
  .group(yearAvgGroup)
  .valueAccessor(kv => kv.value.sum / kv.value.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is only concerned with producing the data, you can use d3-nest, without crossfilter, to average each year:

Parsing the date value, you can then format the date as a year to create a key. This groups values by key, then we rollup those values with a function to calculate the mean for a given year:

```
var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");  // takes: "1900-01"
var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y");   // gives: "1900"

var means = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return format(parse(d.date)); })
  .rollup(function(values) { return d3.mean(values, function(d) {return d.value; }) })
  .entries(data);
```

Which gives us the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "key": "1900",
    "value": 39380000000
  },
  {
    "key": "1999",
    "value": 20000000000
  }
]
```

```js
var data = [
    { date: "1900-01", value: 72000000000},
    { date: "1900-02", value: 58000000000},
    { date: "1900-03", value:  2900000000},
    { date: "1900-04", value: 31000000000},
    { date: "1900-05", value: 33000000000},
    { date: "1999-11", value: 30000000000},
    { date: "1999-12", value: 10000000000},
];

var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m");
var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

var means = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return format(parse(d.date)); })
    .rollup(function(values) { return d3.mean(values, function(d) {return d.value; }) })
    .entries(data);
    
console.log(means);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```